# FFMPEG: av_read_frame() return error AVERROR_EXIT?

Tags: ffmpeg, decode, h.264, ip-camera

I'm using `FFMPEG` to decode `H264` stream from IP Camera. Sometimes the function `av_read_frame()` return error `AVERROR_EXIT`.

I tested with two cameras. In here, the camera in `LAN network` worked fine with no error, but the camera in `WAN network` usually return `AVERROR_EXIT`.

I have searched on the internet, but I didn't find the solution yet.

Someone can show me the problem?

Thanks,

T&T

Answer (score 2):

probably its because of interrupt callback timeout fired. once you have poor network connectivity and next frame from camera delays for more then 5 seconds, timeout fires and av_read_frame returns